# How can I tell what Pokemon I will get from an Egg?

Tags: pokemon-series

I am gonna try to hatch a Shiny Pokemon via the Masuda method, and I would like to know if there is a way to tell what the Pokemon will be before the egg hatches.

For example I'm gonna try to breed Feraligatr with Greninja to get a shiny Froakie with timid (Greninja has it).

But how do I know the egg won't hatch a Totodile?

Answer (score 9):

**Hatched Pokemon will always be of the mother's Pokemon type...**
...except when breeding with a Ditto.

- If Greninja is female and Feraligatr is male, then you will always hatch Froakies
- Greninja is male and Feraligatr is female, then you will get Totodiles
- If they are both the same gender (both male or both female) then they will be unable to breed.

---

If you are breeding a Pokemon with Ditto, then the gender does not matter - even some [Genderless](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Genderless_Pok%C3%A9mon) Pokemon (like Magnemite) can be bred with Ditto.

Another thing to keep in mind is that Pokemon are grouped into compatible breeding pools, known as 'Egg groups'. Luckily, both Greninja and Feraligatr are in the [Water 1 Egg Group](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Water_1_(Egg_Group)), which means they are compatible.

Comment: My Feraligatr is female so I would get Totodile then. So if I breed Greninja with Ditto instead, I will get Froakie

Comment: @Zayden - Yep that sounds correct. If your Greninja is male, you'll have to breed it with ditto to get Froakies